# Convert to Basic Latin for the websites only support Basic Latin and Latin-1 Supplyment(C#)

Tags: c#

When my website send customer's billing information to my vendors, they only accept the characters of **Basic Latin** and **Latin-1 Supplement**.

They also want me to convert the characters not belonging to Basic Latin and Latin-1 Supplement, into **Basic Latin**.

I got an example, which belongs **Latin Extended-A**, and can be converted/changed into **Basic Latin**, in the following C# codes:

```
StringBuilder outPut = new StringBuilder("şöphiaa");
              outPut.Replace('ö', 'o');
              outPut.Replace('ş', 's');
              outPut.Replace('ı', 'i');
              outPut.Replace('ğ', 'g');
```

However, I am wondering is there any way to cover more characters' mapping/conversion?

Comment: You can take inspiration from Lucene's [ASCIIFoldingFilter](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/ASCIIFoldingFilter.java) for that. It's pretty thorough.

Comment: Thank you Lucas. This almost includes everything.